# Installing NuGet with ExchangeOnlineManagement, how to find the current version (or uninstall it)?

Tags: powershell

While [installing the ExchangeOnlineManagement module](https://www.alitajran.com/install-exchange-online-powershell-v2/) the "NuGet provider" will be installed automatically. As far as I understand it is used for package management which I'm not yet very familiar with. I tried to find out more about it but I already failed on how to check if it is installed.

`Get-Package` and `get-module` as well as `Get-InstalledModule` doesn't return any results for NuGet and researching the matter I came across several sites on how to check the version and/or do a manual installation (e.g. [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-packageprovider?view=powershell-7.2), [here](https://www.alitajran.com/unable-to-install-nuget-provider-for-powershell/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964935/get-nuget-exe-version-from-command-line)) but so far nothing worked for me.

I'm sure this is a simple matter, but so far my search results weren't very successfully or I'm on the wrong track. How do I find out if NuGet is installed and get my current NuGet Version?

**Update**:

With help from Reddy Lutonadio I managed to get the version through `Get-PackageProvider`. I haven't figured out though how to uninstall it, neither `Uninstall-module -Name NuGet` nor `Uninstall-Package -Name NuGet` seem to work for PackageProvider-modules. (According to [github](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/165) this seem to be an issue). Is there a way to deinstall it via a cmdlet or manually?

I also managed install Nuget manually via `Install-module -Name Nuget` but it seems to be a different version: it's **not** shown through `Get-PackageProvider` (but through `get-module`). I don't know yet how to install it the same way it gets intalled through the ExchangeOnline module.

Note: `(Get-PackageProvider -name nuget).providerpath` returns a dll: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.4.7\fullclr\Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider.dll`

Comment: Have you tried Get-Package? What is its output?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio good idea, `Get-Package * | select name, source, providername | sort name | ft` gets me a long listing, but nothing if I filter for `nu` or `get`.

Comment: I don't think nuget is installed on your system. Which version of Powershell are you using? You might have to install/download nuget directly yourself.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio It's a requirement for  the ExchangeOnlineManagement module (it get's installed automatically with it). If I deinstall ExchangeOnlineManagement, nuget does not get deinstalled, and if I install ExchangeOnlineManagement again it won't install nuget module anymore. I assume this is because it's still there from the first installation but I could be wrong. I tried to install it manually (see second link) but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: my powershell version is 5.1.18362.1474 (get-host | select version)

Comment: If you have chocolatey installed, run the command choco install Nuget.CommandLine

Comment: I tried to install install it on Powershell 7.2.0 and it was not successfull. Installing via chocolatey did the trick.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio are you sure it's not installed (see my previous "long message")? If it wasn't nuget that got installed with the ExchangeOnlineManagement module, what exactly was the prerequired package that got installed? An how can I deinstall it (or for that matter find it)?

Comment: If get-package doesn't list it, I still think it not installed (I might also be wrong). What is it listed if you run Get-PackageProvider?

Comment: Is it listed if you run Get-InstalledModule? If not run Install-module -Name Nuget -Force. Then run Get-InstalledModule again.

Comment: no not with Get-InstalledModule but Get-PackageProvider returns with "NuGet 3.0.0.1". I was sure I tried that, but apparently not... unless Get-PackageProvider returns more then the installed packages.

Comment: See my previous comment and try to install it.

Comment: after installing it via `Install-module` it get's also listed via `get-Installedmodule` but with Version 1.3.3 (different from the version I get via `Get-PackageProvider`). I'm confused.

Comment: One is the module version, the other the PackageProvider version. I think you should be alright. But just in case you can wait for another forum member to provide more inputs/ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132738/discussion-between-albin-and-reddy-lutonadio).